# No Boot Ubuntu after update

Tags: 14.04, boot

After an update, Ubuntu will not load. I'm currently on Gnome Ubuntu 14.04, but this issue has happened to be before on 14.10 and 15.03. It will work for a few weeks, then an update will prompt me to restart, and after selecting Ubuntu from the grub boot menu, I get this:

```
*Starting ACPI daemon [OK]
*SpamAssassin Mail Filter: disabled, see /etc/default/spamassassin [OK]
*speech I dispatcher disabled: edit /etc/default/speech- dispatcher [OK]
*saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned [OK]
*Restoring resolver state... [OK]
```

It will cycle though this message, flicker, then repeat indefinitely.

If I use tty1 to log in and type :

> sudo stop gdm

the computer freezes and I'm forced to manually reboot.

I can boot from grub to a previous instance of Ubuntu (from before the update) but this is, of course, not a good or permament solution

I can't be the only one having this problem because it has happened 3 times before but I can't any info on this. Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi. You're my only hope.

Comment: This issue has resolved itself after another update. But I'm still not sure as to what caused it or what actually fixed it. If anyone has any insight as to what happened or what a better solution might be, I would really appreciate it.